# Swift Sprite Kit call Function again

Tags: ios, loops, swift, sprite-kit

I want to do an infinite loop with my `SKSpriteNodes` / `SKNode`, but the loop doesn't work correctly.

To give you an Idea of my game, there are 2 long objectives, spawned next to each other on the bottom side of screen and with a gap inbetween them.
Between both of the Objectives is the contactNode, which determines if the Player passed through the walls or not, to score a point. 
The Objectives spawn infinitely.

After the game starts, it calls the Function `addObjectives`. After a small delay, I want to call the same Function again, with new Nodes, while the old spawned one are still there and moving to the top with the new ones.

But with my Code, after the Nodes reach the point given in the `Update:`, they stop and the scene calls the Function again and the new Nodes move upon to the point and stop again.An infinite loop.

I don't want to stop the Nodes after `addObjectives` is called again, they should spawn from the bottom of the screen and move to the top, and then being removed, while there will always come new Objectives from the bottom.

How can I do that?

```
...
var contactNode = SKNode()
...

func addObjectives(){

    O1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Objective.png")
    O1.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width / 1.3, height: self.frame.size.height / 17)
    O1.position = positions[randomPosition()]
    O1.zPosition = 3

    ...

    self.addChild(O1)

    O2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Objective.png")
    O2.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width / 1.3, height: self.frame.size.height / 17)
    O2.position = CGPoint(x: O1.position.x + CGFloat(Gap), y: O1.position.y)
    O2.zPosition = 3

    ...

    self.addChild(O2)

    contactNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:CGSize(width: CGFloat(Gap) / 2, height: O1.size.height))
    contactNode.position = CGPoint(x: O1.position.x + (CGFloat(Gap) / 2), y: O1.position.y - 20)
    contactNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    contactNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ScoreCategory
    contactNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PlayerCategory
    contactNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

    self.addChild(contactNode)
}

//Called in the Update Method

func ScrollingMauer(){

    O1.position = CGPointMake(O1.position.x, O1.position.y + Speed)
    O2.position = CGPointMake(O2.position.x, O2.position.y + Speed)
    contactNode.position = CGPointMake(contactNode.position.x, contactNode.position.y + Speed)

    if(O1.position.y > self.frame.size.height + O1.size.height)
    {
        O1.removeFromParent()
    }

    if(O2.position.y > self.frame.size.height + O2.size.height)
    {
        O2.removeFromParent()
    }

    if(contactNode.position.y > self.frame.size.height + Mauer2.size.height)
    {
        contactNode.removeFromParent()
    }

    // Here the Function is called again, but the previous spawned
    Objectives stop and the new Objectives come from the bottom to the top.

    if(O1.position.y > self.frame.size.height / 3)
    {
        self.addObjectives()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error since `contactNode` has already been added to the scene so adding it again will produce this error since `contactNode` already has a parent.

You could use a boolean flag indicating if the node was already added and add it only once:

```
    contactNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:CGSize(width: CGFloat(Gap) / 2, height: O1.size.height))
    contactNode.position = CGPoint(x: O1.position.x + (CGFloat(Gap) / 2), y: O1.position.y - 20)
    contactNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    contactNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ScoreCategory
    contactNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PlayerCategory
    contactNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

    if !self.contactNodeAdded {
        self.addChild(contactNode)
        self.contactNodeAdded = true
    }
```

and in your `ScrollingMauer` method:

```
if(contactNode.position.y > self.frame.size.height + Mauer2.size.height)
    {
        contactNode.removeFromParent()
        self.contactNodeAdded = false
    }
```

(You could also search the node by name but that will be less efficient, especially when called on each frame update)

**EDIT:**
If you want a new instance for each contact node create one:

```
contactNode = SKNode()
// set physics body etc..
contactNodesArray.append(contactNode)
```

To keep track of these instances (for removing them later) store them in an array and check each instance of the array as you do in the remove contact node logic:

```
let nodesToRemoveArray: Array<Int> = Array();
for (index, node) in enumerate(contactNodesArray) {
    if(node.position.y > self.frame.size.height + Mauer2.size.height)
    {
        node.removeFromParent()
        nodesToRemoveArray.append(index);
    }
}

for indexToRemove in nodesToRemoveArray {
    contactNodesArray.removeATIndex(indexToRemove)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But I don't want to add contactNode only once, it should be always added with the other 2 SpriteNode`s. Also, how can I call the Function `addObjectives` again, without stopping the old objectives that have been added?
I update my Post and added the Game Idea to clarify the Project.

Comment: So why not create the contact node just before you set its attributes ?

Comment: Isn`t that exactly what I made? I create contactNode with the objectives to move them together. contactNode is a simple SKNode with only a physicsBody. If I missunderstood you, please clarify it for me!

Comment: but you use the same instance. Create a new node with : contactNode = SKNode(). I edited my answer, let me know if it is more clear now

Comment: I understood it now. But contactNode will be called even before the "old" contactNode is removed (it will be removed on top of the screen, while it should be spawned again at self.frame.size.height / 3). The Error code is gone. How can I now get the wanted result? I updated my post.

Comment: The code I provided should keep old contact nodes on screen until removed while new contact nodes will be added when needed. Did you try it ?

Comment: Yes, but I want the old SKSpriteNodes to be in the scene aswell, but also going up like its stated in the `Update:Method`.